# Change language based on resources files in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, resources, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 resource file : **Resources.resx**(has some strings in Romanian) and **Resources.en-US.resx** (has the same strings in English).

I only want to change(in a dropdownlist, a listbox,...) witch resource file to use. It could be in _Layout.cshtml. I don't need to detect the user's culture.

Q: How can I select a resource file from a page ?

Edit : Can it be done without changing the default MapRoute ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way you can do it is to have the drop down just redirect the page to a language specific URL (this is quite nice as you can send around language specific links) then in a base class on your controller, set the Thread's locale.

This blog post covers what I am talking about in better detail:  [Localization in ASP.NET MVC – 3 Days Investigation, 1 Day Job](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/05/06/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-3-days-investigation-1-day.aspx)

Comment: This example has .aspx pages not razor .cshtml. And can it be done without changing the default MapRoute ?

Comment: It uses aspx but cshtml razor pages work in the same way, just slightly different syntax (I do this using razor in an applciation just fine).  You also do not need to change the default MapRoute (so non-locale aware URLS will also work), you just need to add an extra route.

Comment: Could you(or anyone) write down the code where I select **Resources.en-US.resx** instead of **Resources.resx** from the folder _App_GlobalResources_ ?

Comment: Since the current thread's locale is set to en-US or whatever you have chosen from the drop down you just use ´@Resources.Welcome´ (or whatever property you want the string for) inside the cshtml page (or controller).  The part that is in charge of setting the thread's locale is in the ExecuteCore method in the base controller (quite near the bottom of the blog post).

Answer (score 4):

Check this [Blog](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/183/Globalization-And-Localization-With-Razor-Web-Pages). 
Without changing default MapRoute.

The _Layout.cshtml page:

```
@using Resources;
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="post">
                @TestResource.SelectLanguage
                <select name="lang">
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="en-GB" @(Culture == "en-GB" ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "")>English</option>
                    <option value="fr-FR" @(Culture == "fr-FR" ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "")>French</option>
                    <option value="de-DE" @(Culture == "de-DE" ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "")>German</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="@TestResource.Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
        @RenderBody()
    </body>
</html>
```

The culture is set within the _PageStart.cshtml file:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";
    if(!Request["lang"].IsEmpty()){
        Culture = UICulture = Request["lang"];
    }
}
```

The final page is the Default page itself:

```
@using Resources;
<h1>@TestResource.Welcome</h1>
<p><img src="images/@TestResource.FlagImage" /></p>
```

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/183/Globalization-And-Localization-With-Razor-Web-Pages